# how to open two r sessions and them parallely in r studio in ubuntu?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, rstudio-server

I have a program that requires parallel running of scripts.one script is the shiny script that gets it data from another script that generates streaming data.i need my dashboard to be dynamic.the second script is an ordinary r script whereas the first one a shiny script.to run the shiny application the data obtained from the r script  is passed to it.

Comment: Set-up a cron job which will run your R script and save the data into an .Rd file which can be accessed by your app

Comment: the data from the second script is being saved as .Rdata is being loaded into the shiny app but i still need to run them parallely